# Find the length of the generator or Does it have an element

Tags: python, iterator, iteration, generator

Hello i have a Code like Below :

```
isEmpty = True
for itrat in  generator():
    isEmpty = False
    break
if isEmpty:
    doSomething()
else:
    dosomethingelse()
```

that test if i have One or mode element in **Generator** Or rather if generator **length > 0** do something,
But I want a **cleaner** code that Show if our **Generator has elements** or not,i dont need to get all value of generators result, **Just know Does it have an element**?

the generator do not have length :
[image: generator len error]

Comment: What is generator() exactly? Have you tried to use len(generator())?

Answer (score 0):

```
from more_itertools import peekable

if peekable([]):
    print('ok')
else:
    print('not ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the len(generator).

```
n=sum(1 for x in generator())

if n==0:
    dosomething()
else:
    dosomethingelse()
```

Comment: No you can't. try `len(iter([]))` e.g.

Comment: Sry, my mistake, i have updated my solution, please check again

Comment: Note that this exhausts the generator. So you know its previous length, but now it's empty :)

Comment: @IoaTzimas If consuming the generator is not an issue per se, at least use a short-circuit logic like `empty = not any(1 for _ in generator())`. Think about infinite generators like `itertools.count`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find out if a general iterator is empty without consuming at least one item. One workaround could go along the following lines:

```
from itertools import chain

def empty_check(gen):
    try:
        x = next(gen)
        return chain([x], gen), False
    except StopIteration:
        return gen, True

gen, empty = empty_check(generator())
if empty:
    # do something 
else:
    # do something else with still complete gen
```